# Criar dois apps Reactjs no mesmo projeto compartilhando node_modules

Tags: react

Estou criando um projeto que tem dois Apps, um para área administrativa e
outro para o usuário.

Dentro do projeto tem as rotas /admin e /user, tudo funciona corretamente, na pasta /src
tem uma pasta components que compartilho entre as duas áreas.

Quando faço o build para publicar o projeto, ele cria os arquivos que em média fica 5MB,se
eu remover toda area administrativa e faço o build novamente o tamanho cai para 2MB.

É possível fazer de alguma forma o build das áreas separadas?

Porque se eu fizer dessa forma \admin vai ter 3MB e \user vai ter 2MB e consequentemente elas irão carregar mais rápido mas, eu não gostaria de perder o compartilhamento dos componentes do mesmo projeto.

Hoje eu trabalho em outros projetos similares a este criando dois apps separados, mas na hora de compartilhar os componentes que são os mesmos, fica complicado copiar tudo novamente para atualizar.

Eu utilizo o create-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou falar da minha experiência em um projeto similar.

Aqui precisavamos criar vários módulos utilizando uma extrutura parecida, nós tinhamos (5 módulos), mas vou simplificar aqui pro seu exemplo.

Core(é quem continha tudo do framework)

Admin(tem somente os componentes e rotas e as regras de negócio, na ideia de plugins)

User(Tinha somente os componentes e rotas , na ideia de plugins)

Acho que você tem que pensar em compartilhar os seus componentes como plugins react e disponibilizar funções que contém as rotas para você registrar em seu core.

Uma ferramenta que nos ajudou bastante a fazer isso foi o [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)(ferramenta de monorepo para js)